# Kernighan & Ritchie. Bitcount

Tags: kernighan-and-ritchie

This opperation is in the book:

```
int bitcount(unsigned x)
{
    int b;

    for (b = 0; x != 0; x >>= 1)
         if (x & 01)
               b++;
    return b;
}
```

but i've tried `if (x & 1)` instead and it gives the same number, so... isn't it the same to use `x & 1` or `x & 01` ? if not, where is the difference?

Comment: 01 = 1 = 0x01 = 0x1. They're all the same number. One is one is one is one. The only time it makes a difference is when you're trying to ensure the compiler allocates a specific sized constant. In this case, the allocation of the constant doesn't matter.

Comment: To expand on Ken White's comment, usually when you're writing binary numbers, you add an extra zero at the start to indicate that this is, well, the start of that number. That makes zero difference for this case, because 1 is bitwise 1.